# UIScrollView in UITableVIewCell won't scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` with scrolling disabled.

In a `UITableViewCell`, I have a `UIScrollView`.

In the `UITableViewCell` subclass, I've implemented :

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{    
    [mainScrollView addSubview:mainContentView];
    mainScrollView.contentSize = mainContentView.bounds.size;
    mainScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

This method is called and the content size is correctly set.

But the `UIScrollView` won't scroll... Do you thing it might come form the `UITableView` ? I've done the same kind of thing in an other app with a `UICollectionView` in a `UITableView` and it worked well though.

Comment: Have you check that all superviews of the scrollview have `userInteraction` set to `YES` ?

Comment: Does your cell content overflows out of the table cell?

Comment: @KIDdAe : It seems to come from there. I'v add a button in my cell but I can't press it. But I can't figure out why...

Comment: @NicolasRoy Try some dirty things to debug :) ! Something like `UIView *view = scrollView.superview; while (view) { view.userInteractionEnable = YES; view = view.superview; }`

Answer (score 12):

I got it !

> What worked for me is this:
>
> `contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`
>
> called after loading my custom cell from nib. It looks like this
>   content view is created and set as a top-level child view after
>   creating views defined in the nib file.

More information here : [Button in UITableViewCell not responding under ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848689/button-in-uitableviewcell-not-responding-under-ios-7)

Comment: I wish i can give u more ups... work great :) thanks