# iOS9 - UITableViewCellContentView is covering up Controls inside Cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nib, xcode7, ios9

I have made a custom UITableViewCell called "SwitchCell" that has a switch. 
In iOS9 Only, using Xcode 7 beta, the Content view in the cell is on top of the switch.  (See screenshot of View Hierarchy.  You can clearly see that the content view of the cell is on top of the other views. ): 
[image]

So all the touches to the UISwitch are intercepted, and the IBAction does not fire. 
In iOS8, this is not a problem.  See screenshot for iOS 8.4 simulator.  You can see that there is no content view on top of the controls: 
[image]

Has anyone had this problem? 
I tried remaking the NIB from scratch, but the same result occurs.

My NIB is a freeform size view with No status bar.  It has two outlets:  one for UILabel, one for UISwitch.

EDIT:  please make sure to check the answer below that asks to verify that the cell's root view is not just a UIView but a UITableViewCell.  This issue may also be a side effect of this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After more investigation and searching, i found my solution here:
[Button in UITableViewCell not responding under ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848689/button-in-uitableviewcell-not-responding-under-ios-7)

What fixed it for me was:

```
cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This prevents the cell content view from taking over the touch events, even though it's on top of the other views.

This issue was not only happening on iOS9, but on iOS7 as well.  In iOS8, the Content view was behind the controls.

Comment: It works here on iOS 9.1 developer preview. Anyways, it makes no sense at all, the contentView IS THE PARENT VIEW ON THE HIERARCHY, shouldn't be on top of the other views.

Comment: I had the same effect with Xcode 7.1.1. Makes me wonder why the UITableViewCellContentView is on top of everything in that cell.

Comment: This solved an issue for me where buttons were tappable before Xcode12, then I upgraded and this line allowed me to access the buttons again which has stopped working.

Answer (score 4):

Problem can be in .xib file for your cell. When you create cell in separate .xib, be sure to drag **UITableViewCell** on canvas, **not UIView**.

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT**

I had an issue where my buttons in my custom tableviewcell swift files were working just fine, but then I upgraded to Xcode 12 and then all of a sudden I couldn't access them anymore (meaning my taps were not being recognized). The cell content view seemed to be interfering in the hierarchy and this like saved me:

```
cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

I put the line in cellForRowAt.

Thank you to @FranticRock

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I was reusing a cell as a .xib. I didn't realise but when I first created the xib the default view that it created was in fact a `UIView` and not a `UITableViewCell`. It seems that at some stage UIKit adds the content view on top of my other elements and therefore interrupts certain events (e.g. touch events).

I resolved this by opening my xib file and dragging a `UITableViewCell` onto the canvas and copying my UI elements from the old view to the new cell.

Afterwards, additional settings also became available in the attributes inspector that matched those for a `UITableViewCell`.