# Cannot edit UITextView inside custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a custom UITableViewCell and a table view. UITableViewCell has UITextView in it. editable is already set to true. But I cannot edit  it.

Blue canvas is TextView and Purple canvas is UITableCellContentView.

[image]

Where am I wrong?

UPDATE:

I found my solution here: [iOS9 - UITableViewCellContentView is covering up Controls inside Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681481/ios9-uitableviewcellcontentview-is-covering-up-controls-inside-cell)

I made     cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

and it works fine now. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you are not able open keyboard on its tap? make sure userInterection set on for it

Comment: Also set proper heught for your cell/textview

Comment: I gave a proper height, also I cut the lorem ipsum text. userInteraction is true but keyboard does not open.

Comment: set UITextView.userInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: it is already set to true

Comment: make sure that there is no any view above the textview with user-interection enabled.

Comment: Seems like UITableViewCellContentView is over TextView. How to arrange those views?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making the MessageBox setEditable and setUserInteractionEnabled, you ALSO have to make sure those properties are enabled in your UITableViewController as well since the UITextView is nested within it!

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
MessageBox.isEditable = true
MessageBox.userInteractionEnabled = true
```