# Can't interact with anything inside a UITableViewCell, I'm being blocked by a bool somewhere, where is it?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm constantly running into this issue, I don't know how to treat UITableViewCells as UIViews.

I added a button to my UITableViewCell:

```
    let btnWidth = self.contentView.frame.size.width * 1.1
    let btnHeight = self.contentView.frame.size.height * 1.6
    btnJoinChannel = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:btnWidth,height:btnHeight))
    btnJoinChannel.setTitle("Join Channel", for: .normal)
    btnJoinChannel.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    btnJoinChannel.backgroundColor = .clear
    btnJoinChannel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(JRegionCell.loadRegion), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.contentView.addSubview(btnJoinChannel)
```

Buttons never work on UITableViewCells by default because some kind of touch gesture value overrides the new button.

What do I configure to prevent this override? I would like users to touch buttons inside `UITableViewCell`s. Basically, my cells need to behave like UIViews.

Comment: are you able to see `Join Channel` title?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button in UITableViewCell not responding under ios 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848689/button-in-uitableviewcell-not-responding-under-ios-7)

Comment: Try to set UITableViewCell selection style as .None

Comment: UIButtons do tend to work ok as cell.accessoryView

Answer (score 0):

Your button is bigger than content view. Buttons don't work if they are out of superview.