# Disabled button in UITableViewCell Xamarin.iOs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have UITableView and each cell has button and text. Actual cell shouldn't be clickable, but button should. When I run in simulator I can hit button, but when deploy to device it is disabled. (edited)

Tried to follow many different steps to fix it from this post [Button in UITableViewCell not responding under ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848689/button-in-uitableviewcell-not-responding-under-ios-7), such as ContentView.UserInteractionEnabled = False; for cell.

All of those for native iOS, maybe for Xamarin there are something else?

Any ideas what am I missing?

UITableViewCell code

```
this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CalendarCell, ActivityModel>();
            set.Bind(CustomerNameLabel).To(a => a.Subject);
            set.Bind(MarkAsMeetingButton).For(a => a.Hidden).WithConversion("ActivityTypeToVisibility");
            set.Bind(MarkAsMeetingButton).To(a => a.SendMessageToViewModelCommand).CommandParameter(BindingContext);
            set.Apply();
        });
        ContentView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
```

UItableView code

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var source = new TableSource(CalendarList);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CalendarView, CalendarViewModel>();
        set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.CalendarList);
        set.Apply();
        CalendarList.Source = source;
        CalendarList.ReloadData();
    }

    public class TableSource : MvxSimpleTableViewSource
    {
        private List<IGrouping<DateTime, ActivityModel>> GroupedCalendarList = new List<IGrouping<DateTime, ActivityModel>>();

        public TableSource(UITableView calendarView) : base(calendarView, "CalendarCell", "CalendarCell")
        {}

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var currentSection = GroupedCalendarList[indexPath.Section].ToList();
            var item = currentSection[indexPath.Row];

            var cell = GetOrCreateCellFor(tableView, indexPath, item);

            var bindable = cell as IMvxDataConsumer;
            if (bindable != null)
                bindable.DataContext = item;

            return cell;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return (nint)GroupedCalendarList[(int)section].Count();
        }

        public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            var label = new UILabel();
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            var titleText = GroupedCalendarList[(int)section].FirstOrDefault().ScheduledStart.Value.Date;
            return label;
        }

        public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return (nint)GroupedCalendarList.Count;
        }

        public override void ReloadTableData()
        {
            if (ItemsSource == null) return;

            var groupedCalendarList = (ItemsSource as List<ActivityModel>).GroupBy(cl => cl.ScheduledStart.Value.Date).ToList();

            GroupedCalendarList = new List<IGrouping<DateTime, ActivityModel>>(groupedCalendarList);

            base.ReloadTableData();
        }
    }
```

This code works absolutely fine for simulator, but doesn't work on device, UIButton in each cell is disabled.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? The UITableView, UITableViewCell and potentially the ViewModel members you're binding to would be useful.

Comment: Added some code, VM is a bit complicated, but there shouldn't be any problems

Comment: What versions of iOS are your simulator and device running? `ContentView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;` is the reason the button in your cell is not clickable; `UserInteractionEnabled` is false for all subviews of `ContentView`. You'll need an alternative solution to disabling the click on the cells while allowing the button to be clicked -- see the suggestions on the Xamarin forums [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15560/how-to-add-a-custom-button-in-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 2):

As @Luke said in the comments of your question said, do not use `ContentView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;`, since this disables any touch events on the whole view of your cell.

To achieve what you need, implement the UITableViewDelegate method `ShouldHighlightRow` and return false:

`public override bool ShouldHighlightRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath rowIndexPath) {
    return false;
}`

Then, the cells will not get highlighted on tap, and the `RowSelected` method will not get called, but your button will be clickable!